# Does installing Google Chrome as a package from Google's website keep it up to date?

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, google-chrome, automatic

Apparently the simplest way to install Chrome is to go to google.com/chrome and download the package but does this keep it up-to-date?

As far as I know if I install some software this way it doesn't auto-update. I need to add a repository to my list so that it's checked for newer versions.

*The other way to install Chrome is to add `http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/` to `/etc/apt/sources.list` and carry on...* Does the first method keep chrome up-to-date like this method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As part of the process of installing the `.deb` package from Google Chrome's website, a file named `google-chrome.list` is added to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`, so you will get automatic updates when you perform `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` in the terminal.

For example, in my case where I have Google Chrome on the dev (unstable) channel, I see:

```
$ ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d | grep chrome
google-chrome-unstable.list
google-chrome-unstable.list.save
```

The installation processes of many `.deb` packages do not add `.list` files to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` though, so in these cases, you will have to manually update such software by installing the updated `.deb` packages again via `sudo dpkg -i`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as part of the installation process you will be asked to consent to the relevant repository being added.